# batch file which opens file which has spaces in file path

Tags: batch-file

Okay so I want to write a batch file which opens a file located in C:\my stuff\ more stuff\more\file.bhf using the start command.

I tried doing 
START "C:\my stuff\ more stuff\more\file.bhf"
but this just ends up opening the command prompt and on the top of the command prompt it says that it is in "C:\my stuff\ more stuff\more\file.ebhf" and then the command prompt does nothing.

I also tried
START "" "C:\my stuff\ more stuff\more\file.bhf"
and 
START "file.bhf" "C:\my stuff\ more stuff\more"

If I remove START, it says that the system cannot find the path.
I want to run file.bhf, basically "double click it" except through the command prompt. When file.bhf is doubled click / when you run file.bhf, it starts up a host session in which other people can connect to your computer

All of them give the same results. Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Perfect, got it to work! You guys were right, I didn't need START and I just converted the file.bhf to a .exe, strangely enough, it worked. Thank you KenWhite and @PhilipKelley !

Comment: Did you try not using `START`? Also, your first paragraph says you want to open a file located in an executable (in `file.exe`, one of your examples uses `file.bhf` instead of `file.exe`, and your final example is trying to start `file.exe` with a parameter of `C:\my stuff\more stuff\more", so it's not doing the same thing at all. Please [edit] your question and clarify exactly which one of the three totally different things you've included here actually applies to what you're trying to accomplish. If you can't explain your question clearly, we can't possibly answer it.

Comment: @Ken White Yea, it still didn't work. If I remove the START then it doesn't open anything, the command prompt just opens and then closes really quickly. And whoops sorry, I meant .bhf not .exe

Comment: When you say "opens a file", what do you mean? What do you actually want do do with that file?

Comment: Add a `PAUSE` as the second line, that will let you see what (if any) results are generated by the first line.

Comment: @Philip Kelley I want to run file.bhf, basically "double click it" except through the command prompt. When file.bhf is doubled click / when you run file.bhf, it starts up a host session in which other people can connect to your computer.

Comment: @Ken White, curiosly, when I first saw this post, only the first line of your comment was visible--the rest showed up when I submitted my first comment. Perhaps you edited it and, through a fluke of timing, we only happened to see that first line?

Comment: @Ken White I have edited it my post. I meant .bhf not .exe, sorry about that. Basically, I want to run file.bhf, basically "double click it" except through the command prompt. When file.bhf is doubled click / when you run file.bhf, it starts up a host session in which other people can connect to your computer.

Comment: Then, presumably, just having the full path + file name will cause the program to execute (though I'm a bit unsure about that .bhf extension). Definitely run with `PAUSE`, see if any messages are generated.

Comment: @Phillip: Possible. :-) I deleted my last comment in case that was the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide additional information there, instead of putting it in comments addressed to a specific user. If you [edit] your question, **everyone** can see that updated detail instead of possibly missing it because they don't read every single comment. (I've asked three times now for you to [edit] your question - oops, **4** times now :-) - and provided a clickable link to help you do so.)

Comment: @PhilipKelley It says that the system cannot find the path if I remove the START.

Comment: @Ken is right--comments are where we ask for clarifications, and those clarifications should be edits to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer will start it properly, you don't need `START` or the name of the executable. You can simply use the filename itself, and Windows will check the file association and launch it properly.

You can test this by just typing this at a command prompt (replace the path with a path to an existing text file on your machine) and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
"C:\Users\user216485\Documents\Readme.txt"
```

Just use this in your batch file:

```
"C:\my stuff\ more stuff\more\file.bhf"
```

Comment: Perfect, got it to work! You guys were right, I didn't need START and I just converted the file.bhf to a .exe, strangely enough, it worked. Thank you KenWhite and @PhilipKelley !

Answer (score 0):

Based on the overlong Comments discussion (in part my fault), I'm going to hazard the guess that your path is wrong. Looking at the second example as currently presented in the question, you have

```
"C:\my stuff\ more stuff\more\file.bhf"
```

...and that embedded space before `more stuff` looks dead wrong to me.